# Rabbitmq-c "SSL peer cert verification failed"

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-c

I'm trying to connect to RabbitMQ server using SSL but i'm getting this error "SSL peer cert verification failed".

I check the certificate using openssl like so:
openssl s_client -connect host:port -CAfile cacert.pem

And got "Verify return code: 0 (ok)" so i believe that the certificate is OK.

I'm trying to use the amqps_bind.c example in [here](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/blob/master/examples/amqps_bind.c).

I only need server verification so I removed the amqp_ssl_socket_set_key().

The code is failing in amqp_socket_open().

Also i have a C# code that can connect to the same server using SSL without any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my issue.

The cacert.pem file that I provided was all the chain of certificates.

After extracting only the root certificate I can connect to the sever.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that check the following config also in your rabbitmq.config

```
{verify,verify_peer},
{fail_if_no_peer_cert,true}]},
```

change those to following if you do not want to verify peer

```
 {verify,verify_none},
 {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}]},
```